# Create Cluster Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, cluster, domain-controller, windows-cluster

I have two virtual machines (Node1, Node2). Node1 set DC, Node2 connecting to domain.enter image description here.

I'm trying to create a cluster, on Tab "Select Servers" add the Nodes. An error adding Node2.

> The node cannot be contacted. Ensure that the node is powered on and
>   is connected to the network

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the dns server of vm2 to the ip address of vm1

Comment: Is well worth it